# Retain original modified timestamp while replacing the new file into the jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am replacing a file into the existing jar file using the java. While i am replacing the new file, remaining files modified time also changing to current timestamp. Please advise what need to do retain the original modified datetime for the other files. I am using the code,

```
    while (entry != null) {
        String name = entry.getName();
        boolean notInFiles = true;
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.getName().equals(name)) {
                notInFiles = false;
                break;
            }
        }
                    if (notInFiles) {
            // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
            // Transfer bytes from the ZIP file to the output file
            int len;
            while ((len = zin.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
        entry = zin.getNextEntry();
    }
    // Close the streams        
    zin.close();
    // Compress the files
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
        // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));
        // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        // Complete the entry
        out.closeEntry();
        in.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jar-files are basicly zipfiles with a different file-type extension, you can mount the jar-file as a [java.nio.file.FileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) using [ZipFileSystemProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html)

Then use [Files.copy(fromPath,toPath,replace)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) to copy the file. This will leave other files in the jar untouched, and will likely be a lot faster.

```
public class Zipper {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
        Path zipPath = Paths.get("c:/test.jar");

        //Mount the zipFile as a FileSysten
        try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipPath,null)) {

            //Setup external and internal paths
            Path externalTxtFile = Paths.get("c:/test1.txt");
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/test1.txt");          

            //Copy the external file into the zipfile, Copy option to force overwrite if already exists
            Files.copy(externalTxtFile, pathInZipfile,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            //Close the ZipFileSystem
            zipfs.close();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't follow this approach as FileSystems is supported in JDK 7 and i am currently using the JDK 6 version. Kindly advise as per the same.